# Error when importing Eclipse project in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, import

When i try to import the eclipse project in android studio it shows me an error like this ..

> - Project OkVizag:C:\Users\G.Bustilla\Desktop\MyWebAppPack\Source_Code_CtrlPlusU\OkVizag\project.properties:
>     Library reference ..\android-support-v7-appcompat could not be found
>
> Path is
>   C:\Users\G.Bustilla\Desktop\MyWebAppPack\Source_Code_CtrlPlusU\OkVizag..\android-support-v7-appcompat
>   which resolves to
>   C:\Users\G.Bustilla\Desktop\MyWebAppPack\Source_Code_CtrlPlusU\android-support-v7-appcompat

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html this link may help you

Comment: try cleaning and then rebuilding the project also deleting the .gradle file and restating the android studio